# Retrieve Dictionary Values from json File

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to parse a json file which is been got from a file stream. Following is my json data

```
{
   "appname":"sine",
    "taborder":  [
            "some",
            "thing",
            "is",
            "went",
            "wrong"  ]
}
```

I am storing the data in a String and trying to deserialize the data. I am trying to show the keys in alert box in the following way

```
 string jsonString = contents;//"{'Name':'Bill', 'Ag:53}";
 you deserializedUser = ReadToObject(jsonString);

 var str = deserializedUser.mainDict.Keys.ToArray();
 MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
```

But i am getting the key value as "null", How to get the key values in proper , pls help me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this hope this helps

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
    JavaScriptRequest obj= DeserializeJavaScriptRequest(typeof(JavaScriptRequest), Resource1.test) as JavaScriptRequest;
    MessageBox.Show(obj.appname +" | " + obj.taborder[0]);
}

public object DeserializeJavaScriptRequest(Type typedeserialize, string eValue)
        {

            Type t = typedeserialize;
        // Get constructor info.
        ConstructorInfo[] ci = t.GetConstructors();           
        object reflectOb = ci[0].Invoke(null);
        MemoryStream confirm_ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eValue));
        DataContractJsonSerializer confirm_ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typedeserialize);
        reflectOb = confirm_ser.ReadObject(confirm_ms);
        confirm_ms.Close();

        return reflectOb;
    }
```

And I made a class

```
 public class JavaScriptRequest
    {
        public string appname { get; set; }
        public string[] taborder { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, (i cann't understand)what is  Resource1.test?

Comment: @Ram sorry it is the json string

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.But it throws this exception:Argument Null Exception Was handled.Value can not be null.
Parameter name: s

Comment: @Ram I didn't get you which parameter 's'

Comment: Sorry Its my mistake CognitiveDesire.Its work fine.thanks for ur help.Once again thanks..:)

Comment: can you pls help me in the ques here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430054/unable-to-parse-dictionary-values