# unable to parse dictionary values

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I am trying to parse a dictionary from a json file as follows

```
{
    "appname":"App Name",
    "taborder":[
                "Street",
                "Country"
                ],
    "home":{
        "type":"grid",
        "items":[
                 "Street",
                 "Country"
                 ]
        }
}
```

At first i am unable to get the details of `appname` and `taborder` and my question regarding it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406881/retrieve-dictionary-values-from-json-file/11407593#comment15072881_11407593) . I got a solution for there and by implementing it i got the values of `taborder and appname`

In the same way i am trying to retrieve the value of a dictionary as follows

"home":{
        "type":"grid",
        "items":[
                 "appointments",
                 "reachus",
                 ]
        }

Following is my piece of code

```
public class JavaScriptRequest
    {
        public string appname { get; set; }
        public List<string> taborder { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> home { get; set; }
    }

    JavaScriptRequest obj = DeserializeJavaScriptRequest(typeof(JavaScriptRequest), contents) as JavaScriptRequest;
    MessageBox.Show(obj.appname+obj.home);
```

how to get the values from the dictionary, pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this class structure

```
 public class JavaScriptRequest
    {
        public string appname { get; set; }
        public string[] taborder { get; set; }
        public JavaScriptRequest1 home { get; set; }

    }
    public class JavaScriptRequest1
    {
        public string type{get;set;}
        public string[] items{get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it works great but i have a doubt,if i use dictionary(public Dictionary<string, string> home { get; set; }) instead of our class structure(JavaScriptRequest1 home).i cannot get the values.plz clarify it..